# Knockout js: How rebind item in template?

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js, reload

I want to rebind/reevaluate whether a custom "template" button should be visible or not. I can't figure out how to without reloading the whole page so the whole model gets reevaluated.

if you look at the code below I have created two template buttons called "header-button". What I want to achieve is to create some sort of method that can be called upon to reevaluate the "display" property of just one of the buttons (maybe based on the "id" property?). 
On my real page I have like 20 buttons that more or less each have their individual display rules and reloading the whole page to make them show/hide correctly seems a bit ineffective...

HTML:

```
<header-button params='title: "Resolve Case",
             buttonText: "RESOLVE",
             onclick: parent.ResolveCase,
             display: !caseIsResolved(), 
             id: "resolve"
             '></header-button>

<header-button params='title: "Resolve this case and open next case",
             buttonText: "RESOLVE & NEXT",
             onclick: parent.ResolveAndOpenNextCase,
             display: !caseIsResolved(),
             id: "update"
             '></header-button>
```

Javascript viewmodel:

```
ko.components.register('header-button', {
  viewModel: function (params) {

    this.imgSrc = ko.observable(params.src);
    this.title = ko.observable(params.title);
    this.onclick = params.onclick;
    this.background = params.background;
    this.cssClass = "clickable";
    this.buttonText = params.buttonText;
    this.display = ko.observable(true);
    this.id = "";

    if (params.buttonText == undefined || params.buttonText == 'undefined')
    { this.buttonText = ""; }

    if (params.display == undefined || params.display == 'undefined')
    { this.display = true; }
    else {
      this.display = params.display;
    }

    if (params.id != undefined && params.id != 'undefined') {
      this.id = params.id;
    }
  },
  template: '<div class="clickable toolbarContainer" style="display: inline; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle" data-bind=" attr:{id: id}, visible: display,  click: onclick">' +
    '<img data-bind=" attr:{ src: imgSrc, title: title}, style:{verticalAlign: \'bottom\', background: background, width: 16, height: 16, marginTop: 4}" ></img>' +
    '&nbsp;<span class="headerButton" data-bind=" attr:{title: title}, text: buttonText" ></span></div>'
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings();
});
```

Comment: would it be possible to set up a small fiddle to illustrate your problem. Knockout has Dependency Tracking: Implicitly set up chains of relationships between model data, to transform and combine it so you should not need to reload the page.

Comment: Perhaps is a typo, but `parent` should be `$parent` (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).  I provide an example (without `$parent` !!) that works: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WEJdmK.  Perhaps the problem is with `$parent`.

Comment: Jose Luis, I want to create a method that can change the visibility for one of the buttons. When they are bound when the page loads they call the function "caseIsResolved" to determine whether they should be visible or not without having to reload the page.

Comment: Please, could you update your question and provide your ViewModel? `caseIsResolved` is not an observable?